# Reason why this C program stopped working

Tags: c

I wonder why this program stopped working when I increase the value of array a[]
If it has, plaese tell me how to increase this value without crashing
Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

    int i, j, save;
    char a[2082001];
    memset(a,'1',2082000);
    for (i=2;i<=2082000;i++)
    {
        if (a[i]=='1')
        {
            save=i;
            for (j=i*2;j<=2082000;j+=i)
                a[j]='0';
        }
    }
    printf("save = %d",save);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It may be stack overflow. Try adding `static` before `char a[2082001]` and see if the program crashes to determine it is the cause or not.

Comment: Let me guess, you're trying this on Windows, which only have a default 1MB default stack space per process? Now try to guess what happens when you try to create a 2MB array on the stack.

Comment: What do you mean with "Increase the value"? How do you do that? The current program works without problems...

Comment: And after you fix the stack overflow problem, change `memset(a,'1',2082000);` to `memset(a, '1', 2082001);` or preferably, `memset(a, '1', sizeof a);`

Comment: 'stopped working' - what?  Error messages. please!

Answer (score -2):

Basic signed integer type. Capable of containing at least the [−32767, +32767] range; thus, it is at least 16 bits in size,

that takes j out of bounds.

Comment: It was very long time ago that `int` was only 16 bits. On any 32-bit system (and these days 64-bit systems) in production the last 30 years or so `int` is 32 bits. By the way, the range you show is wrong, it goes down to -32768.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The range is not wrong. See N1256 5.2.4.2.1, which says that the least in absolute value of `INT_MIN` is `-32767`

Comment: @MikeCAT On one's complement systems yes. Few of those around though, even fewer than 16-bit systems I would guess. :)